# How to implement Microservices with Authentication Server(OAuth2,0 and JWT), Zuul and Eureka services?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I'm using Spring boot Microservices Architecture for our application. In our Project we are using OAuth2, Jwt, Zuul and Eureka Services, my doubt is that do I need to implement these services as an independent service or I can develop all the Services into a Single Application.

If I have to implement as a Single Application what is the better approach to do. Please clarify

Answer (score 1):

With you current stack you can have below independent components:

Discovery Service - Eureka Server
Reverse proxy - Netflix zuul
Identity provider (IdP) service - Spring security over OAuth 2.0
Service Provider - Any other micro service in your application

You can register only Zuul server with IdP if rest of your services are going to be part of a private network behind some kind of firewall.